# Mysqli multi query not updating all fields

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I will preface by stating I am fairly new at any type of programming. 
I am working on a school assignment for video store inventory system, and I am having trouble with a multi query statement. I am attempting to update 2 fields in different tables. I have successfully updated the video table's inventory with an increment operator, but the rental table's return date will not update. I do not get any errors. However, there is not change in the empty field in the database.

I'll upload what I believe to be relevant code.

**This is the HTML for the form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="returnform" id="returnform" action="" method="post">
    <div align="center" class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Rental number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" name="Rental_ref_num" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Enter reference number..." required="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input id="Returned_date" name="Returned_date" type="hidden">
    <input id="Movie_id" name="Movie_id" type="hidden">

    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Return">
    </div>
</form>
```

**I have some Javascript which sets the current date and sends it to a hidden form field.**

```
<script>
    var mydate=new Date()
    var theyear=mydate.getYear()
    if (theyear < 1000)
        theyear+=1900
    var theday=mydate.getDay()
    var themonth=mydate.getMonth()+1
    if (themonth<10)
        themonth="0"+themonth
    var theday=mydate.getDate()
    if (theday<10)
        theday="0"+theday

    var displayfirst=theyear
    var displaysecond=themonth
    var displaythird=theday
```

document.returnform.Returned_date.value=displayfirst+displaysecond+displaythird

**The PHP and queries**

```
<?php
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', 'AMerica12', 'videostoremodel' );

    $rd = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Returned_date']);
    $rrf = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Rental_ref_num']);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT Movie_id FROM rental_table where Rental_ref_num ='".$rrf."'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $name = $row['Movie_id'];
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $sql = "UPDATE `rental_table` 
                SET (`Returned_date` = '$rd') 
                WHERE (`Rental_ref_num` = '$rrf');";

    $sql = "UPDATE `video_table` 
                SET `Amount_inventory` = `Amount_inventory` + 1 
                WHERE (`Movie_id` = '$name');";

    $result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

I'm sorry for the long post. However, I've searched for hours, and no matter what, I cannot figure out why the return date will not update in the rental_table. Once again, I get no error prompts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should use mysqli error, this way you figure out for yourself what is going wrong: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: I have. For the sake of brevity, I decided not to include it in the original post. However, I still get no error prompts.

Comment: see my answer/ Saty's answer. but you the first query will throw an error i'm pretty sure. but at this moment it's not being executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems. One is the brackets you have in the first query in the `SET` statement. There is no reason for brackets there and they're not allowed there. use this instead:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `rental_table` 
        SET `Returned_date` = '$rd'
        WHERE (`Rental_ref_num` = '$rrf');"
```

Second you have to concatenate the queries, at the moment you're overwriting the first query with the second one. so use this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `rental_table` 
        SET `Returned_date` = '$rd' 
        WHERE (`Rental_ref_num` = '$rrf');";

$sql .= "UPDATE `video_table` 
            SET `Amount_inventory` = `Amount_inventory` + 1 
            WHERE (`Movie_id` = '$name');";

$result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $sql)
```

Instead of doing that i would suggest to execute 2 seperate queries instead, you can also easily implement error catching this way:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `rental_table` 
        SET `Returned_date` = '$rd' 
        WHERE (`Rental_ref_num` = '$rrf');";
if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    echo "Errormessage: ". mysqli_error($mysqli);
}

$sql = "UPDATE `video_table` 
            SET `Amount_inventory` = `Amount_inventory` + 1 
            WHERE (`Movie_id` = '$name');";
if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    echo "Errormessage: ". mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was almost to the point of banging my head on the walls. :-)

At first I simply attempted to apply the initial modification you recommended, and it did not throw any errors, but the table `Returned_date` still failed to update. 

Executing two separate queries, however, seemed to do the trick. Thanks again. I think will call it a day for now. This was enough frustration for one day. Good night.

Comment: Executing two separate queries seems good! But what problem you facing while using multi query??

Comment: No problem, i forgot tot mention but maybe you want tot start a mysqli transaction before and commit after so  both queries are executed or neither if there is an error. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are one problem in your code: you run only one sql update query. Just replace your original code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `rental_table` 
        SET (`Returned_date` = '$rd') 
        WHERE (`Rental_ref_num` = '$rrf');";

$sql = "UPDATE `video_table` 
        SET `Amount_inventory` = `Amount_inventory` + 1 
        WHERE (`Movie_id` = '$name');";

$result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $sql)
```

With code below:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `rental_table` 
        SET (`Returned_date` = '$rd') 
        WHERE (`Rental_ref_num` = '$rrf');";
$result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $sql)

$sql = "UPDATE `video_table` 
        SET `Amount_inventory` = `Amount_inventory` + 1 
        WHERE (`Movie_id` = '$name');";
$result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $sql)
```

Comment: For run only one query we use `mysqli_query()` not `mysqli_multi_query()`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I was not sure if it was considered a single query or multi, since I was attempting to modify two table.

Comment: In your case you should use concat and multi query. But I was not careful while read your question and make this answer.